# When is the D matrix constituted of the eigen values on the diagonal line?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my lecture notes it is said that if a matrix is diagonalisable then automatically the matrix D in $P^-1AP = D $ Is constituted of the eigen values on the diagonal line.

However earlier in my notes, it is said that for ex: a 3x3 matrix always has 3 eigenvalues and if they're distinct than automatically the matrix is always diagonalisable.

In a training exercise, I found $\lambda_1=1 , \lambda_2= -2, \lambda_3= -2 $. We have two eigen values that are not distinct. In the solution of that exercise, they just put those eigen values on the diagonal line and form the matrix D without any further explanation.

I want to know why they did that, I thought you had to have three distinct values to always be diagonalisable. Don't you need some further verifications before doing what they did?

Comment: I think you might be missing some context in your notes. A real $3\times3$ matrix does have three eigenvalues, but two of them might be complex. In that case, the matrix does have distinct eigenvalues, but it is _not_ diagonalizable over the reals.

Comment: When you learn about minimal polynomials, you’ll find that a necessary and sufficient condition for diagonalizability is that the minimal polynomial splits into linear factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ can be diagonalisable without having distinct eigenvalues. Having distinct eigenvalues is a sufficient but not necessary condition.

To check if $A$ is diagonalisable, you have to check if the algebraic multiplicity of every eigenvalue is equal to its geometric multiplicity: that is, the power of $(x-\lambda)$ in the characteristic polynomial is equal to the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$. This space is precisely the space of solutions to $(A-\lambda I)\underline{x}=\underline{0}$.

In your example, you'll have to check if the solution space to $(A+2I)x=0$ has dimension $2$. If it does, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=-2$ is equal to its algebraic multiplicity, meaning $A$ is diagonalisable (the geometric multiplicity is always less than or equal to the algebraic multiplicity, and since the other eigenvalue's algebraic multiplicity is $1$, its geometric multiplicity is also $1$), and you can safely put the eigenvalues in the diagonal, $D=\operatorname{diag}(1, -2, -2)$. To find the diagonalising matrix $P$ which satisfies $A=P^{-1}DP$, you'll have to find an eigenvector of $\lambda=1$ and two **linearly independent** eigenvectors for the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=-2$, and put those in the columns of $P$.

Comment: Nicely explained, thank you!